# Convert time format in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am getting time in format

`$cursor=new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));
echo $cursor->format("h:i a");`

So the output is 01:00 pm

And I need to convert the output to something like

13:00

How can I do this?

Comment: see the format table here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you **DO NOT** want leading zero's...such as 1:00 instead of 01:00...

```
echo $cursor->format("G:i");
```

If you **DO** want leading zero's...

```
echo $cursor->format("H:i");
```

In any case, I recommend taking a peeksy at the documentation...

[PHP Date Format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

Wow you could have read the **[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**, use capital `H`. See the `format` section on that page

```
echo $cursor->format("H:i");
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/M0BB2Tdf)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `G:I` format to do this. Use the code below

```
<?php
$cursor=new DateTime("now",new DateTimeZone("Australia/Melbourne"));
echo $cursor->format("G:i a");
```

Hope this helps you